# Xamarin c# SetLooping missing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, method-missing

I'm novice in programming and this is my first project ever in c# xamarin. I want to set loop on that MediaPlayer but SetLooping method is missing in Android.Media.
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community. Here is my code. 
Thanks in advance for any feedback :D

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Preferences;
using Android.Views.Animations;

namespace App2
{
    [Activity(Label = "FirstApp 1.34", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        MediaPlayer music;

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            music.Pause();

        }

        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            music.Release();
            base.OnDestroy();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            music.Start();
            base.OnResume();
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        { 
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            music = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.bgsound);
            music.SetVolume(0.7f, 0.7f);
            music.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetLooping` method is mapped as a property in Xamarin.Android and you should use the `Looping` property instead. Take a look at: [Android.Media.MediaPlayer.Looping Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Media.MediaPlayer.Looping/)

Try this on your code

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        music = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.bgsound);
        music.SetVolume(0.7f, 0.7f);
        music.Start();
        music.Looping = true;
    }
```